# How convert new lines to actual \n when writing javascript array within php loop

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, newline

I have a piece of code which writes a JS array of objects within the PHP code (retrieved from a mysql database) like this :

```
echo "var tab = [\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($resultat)){
$numero = $row[0];
$notes = $row[1];
echo "{\n";
echo "numero:\"".$numero."\",";
echo "notes:\"".$notes."\" ";
echo "\n},";
}
echo "\n]";
```

(I simplified the code for the purposee... in the actual code the last comma is deleted)

The problem is : if I have new lines into $notes, it brakes the JS array and generates a JS parse error, since the new line is written as a real new line in the JS code, and not as "\n" as it should be.

For example, the text

```
"foo bar
foo bar"
```

Should be written in the JS array :

```
"foo bar\nfoo bar".
```

All I want to do is writing "\n" in place of actual new lines.

I tried this :

```
$notes = str_replace("\n", '\n', $row[1]);
```

But no success.
Any idea ?

Comment: **Don't handcraft your JSON string.** Save the trouble and just use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for you to convert your PHP array into JSON, is to use the `json_encode` function:

```
$rows = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultat)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

I can't remember if there is an easier way to get the entire result set through the older mysql functions. I would recommend you to use PDO instead of `mysql_query`, `mysql_fetch_row`, etc.: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

**Edit:**

If you want to assign the JSON object to a variable, e.g. inside a `<script>` block, do this:

```
<script>
var myArray = <?= json_encode($rows) ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Ronni. It's the perfect answer and it works like a charm ! (I didn't know this function json_encode... it's powerful!)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work if you escape out the slash in php, like this: `\\n`

I haven't tested this, but if I remember correctly this should work.

But, if all you are trying to do is display the text on an HTML page why not use a `<br />` tag in place of `\n` that would give you an actual break where the `\n` would just start a new line in your code but just display as a space in the browser

Comment: Non, I don't want to display the text on the page as html (i would have used nl2br for that), it's for populating a JS array dynamically.